# Set orientation per page using Migradoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using PdfSharp/Migradoc (WPF nuget package) to create a PDF which is sent as an attachment to an e-mail.

I need the first page of the document to be in portrait orientation and then the rest of the pages (sections) to be in landscape orientation.

Is this possible in some way?

I'm adding a new section for each page I need rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit hurry there making my post. For future purpose, this is the solution:

Simply set the orientation on the new `Section` like so:

```
Section priceLineSection = pdfDocument.AddSection();
priceLineSection.PageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
```

Works like a charm :-)